# The image of the ring is a semi-ring? Measure theory

Tags: measure-theory

I'm starting to learn measure theory. I know that any ring is a semiring, the converse is not true. How do I prove that for $f: A \rightarrow B$, some system of subsets of $A$, which is a ring, goes into a system of subsets of В, which will be a semiring?

Comment: There are some clarifications that would be good. Are you assuming A is a ring, B is a semiring? And are you saying that a ring of subsets of A will be sent by f to a semiring of subsets of B? And by 'goes to' and 'sent', do you mean for $\mathcal{A}$ the subsets of A you look at $\{f(S):S\in\mathcal{A}\}$?

Comment: More precisely A_1 is a system of subsets of the set A and A_1 is a ring, B_1 is a system of subsets of the set B. f(A_1) = {f(S):S ∈ A}. B_1 is the image of A_1, how can I prove that B_1 is a semiring?